# How to center this menu with CSS?

Tags: css, menu, center

[This is the menu I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMgVg.png)

I'm having this problem that I can't solve... why it doesn't center?

I've already tried a lot of stuff here on this website, but I can't understand it all, can someone help me with the problem and try to explain to me how to center it?

```css
.menu {
 font: 16px 'Dosis', sans-serif; font-weight: 600;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 border: none;
}

.menu li { position: relative; float: left; }

.menu li a {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 14px 11px 0 11px;
 height: 36px;
}

.menu li a:hover { color: #FC0; background: #F60 url(../imgs/bg-menu2.png) repeat-x; }

.menu li ul {
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 top: 50px;
 left: 0px;
 background: #F60;
 display: none;
 float: left;
 z-index: 999;
}

.menu li:hover ul ul { display: none; }

.menu li:hover ul, .menu li ul li:hover ul, .menu li.over ul, .menu li ul li.over ul { display: block; }

.menu li ul li { display: block; width: 200px; }

li.border0 { border: none; }

.menu li ul li ul { z-index: 998; top: 0px; left: 200px; }

body { behavior: url(csshover.htc); }
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="../index.html" title="INÍCIO">INÍCIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="../apresentacao.html" title="PROGRAMAÇÃO">PROGRAMAÇÃO</a></li>
    <li><a href="../comissao.html" title="HOSPEDAGEM">HOSPEDAGEM</a></li>
    <li><a href="../local.html" title="SUBMISSÃO">SUBMISSÃO</a></li>
    <li><a href="../inscricao.html" title="LOCAL">LOCAL</a></li>
    <li><a href="../trabalhos.html" title="INSCRIÇÃO">INSCRIÇÃO</a></li>
    <li><a href="../programacao.html" title="CONTATO">CONTATO</a></li>    
 </ul>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r0t6p04b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `text-align: center` for `.menu` and unfloat a menu items:

(I've added `background: teal;` for visibility of white words)

```css
.menu {
 font: 16px 'Dosis', sans-serif; font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 background: teal;
}

.menu li { 
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
 }

.menu li a {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 14px 11px 0 11px;
 height: 36px;
}

.menu li a:hover { color: #FC0; background: #F60 url(../imgs/bg-menu2.png) repeat-x; }

.menu li ul {
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 top: 50px;
 left: 0px;
 background: #F60;
 display: none;
 float: left;
 z-index: 999;
}

.menu li:hover ul ul { display: none; }

.menu li:hover ul, .menu li ul li:hover ul, .menu li.over ul, .menu li ul li.over ul { display: block; }

.menu li ul li { display: block; width: 200px; }

li.border0 { border: none; }

.menu li ul li ul { z-index: 998; top: 0px; left: 200px; }

body { behavior: url(csshover.htc); }
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="../index.html" title="INÍCIO">INÍCIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="../apresentacao.html" title="PROGRAMAÇÃO">PROGRAMAÇÃO</a></li>
    <li><a href="../comissao.html" title="HOSPEDAGEM">HOSPEDAGEM</a></li>
    <li><a href="../local.html" title="SUBMISSÃO">SUBMISSÃO</a></li>
    <li><a href="../inscricao.html" title="LOCAL">LOCAL</a></li>
    <li><a href="../trabalhos.html" title="INSCRIÇÃO">INSCRIÇÃO</a></li>
    <li><a href="../programacao.html" title="CONTATO">CONTATO</a></li>    
 </ul>
```